# Obtener lista de enteros usando stdin.readline()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Yo uso esto la siguiente entrada para una ingresar una lista de números, por ejemplo esta lista: 1 2 3 4 5 6

```
a=stdin.readline().strip().split()
```

si le doy `print(a)` el me muestra `['1','2','3','4','5','6']`, mi duda es si se puede  modificar esa entrada de tal forma que me muestre la lista de números enteros(`[1,2,3,4,5,6]`) mas no de strings, ¿o simplemente no se podrá?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes hacer el casting de forma explícita a `int`, por ejemplo mediante listas por compresión:

```
from sys import stdin

a = [int(n) for n in stdin.readline().strip().split()]
```

O usando `input()`:

```
a = [int(n) for n in input().split()]
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que si se ingresa un valor que no pueda ser transformado en `int` se obtendrá una excepción (`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10`), esto incluye subcadenas con el punto decimal ('4.2', '7.25', etc). Si acepta enteros con signo ('-3'. '-4', '+7', etc).